# How can I correctly forward traffic from a container to a NodePort service with Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running Minikube on an m1 mac with the docker daemon. I have a container in a pod serving HTTP on port 7777; according to the documentation, I can use a combination of a nodeport and the `minikube service` command to expose it to the local machine. My configuration yaml file is pretty simple as well:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: door-controls
  labels:
    type: door-controls
spec:
  containers:
    - image: door_controls
      name: door-controls
      imagePullPolicy: Never
      ports:
      - containerPort: 7777
        name: httpz
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: door-control-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    type: door-controls
  ports:
  - name: svc-http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: httpz
```

Running this in minikube and then attempting to use minikube service will expose the running process on a random port. From a machine inside the network, I can `wget` the pod IP on port 7777 and get data back, so I know the pod is correctly serving traffic. I *also* can wget the `door-control-service` nodeport service from inside the network on port 80 and get traffic back, so I know that the `door-control-service` configuration is working. But no amount of futzing will allow me to access the `door-control-service` inside the network via the `nodeport` (which is randomly generated in the port ~30k range, and the browser launched by minikube service never returns data so I can't access it outside of that range either.

What am I doing wrong? Or more generally, how can I debug this issue? I am new to kubernetes and not sure where in the logs I should be looking for errors in the first place.

Comment: What URL are you trying to connect to, and from where are you trying to connect to it?  From another Kubernetes Pod running in the same Minikube you should be able to connect to `http://door-control-service` using the default HTTP port 80.  You say "container" several times in this question; is this a container in a Pod in Minikube, or is it running somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, it is a container in a pod in minikube.  I cleaned the question up a little; I can put the IP addresses if they are useful but since they are per-pod (and per deploy) I was guessing maybe not so much.

Comment: In the last paragraph you talk about making calls inside the cluster, and what you say there is true: you can connect to `http://door-control-service` using the Service port (80) but not the randomly-assigned node port.  If you looked up a node IP somehow you could use the node port but this is only occasionally useful (connecting to the "local" replica of a DaemonSet-managed pod, and even then it usually has a well-known port).

Comment: I suspect the `minikube service` is your actual problem.  What happens when you try to connect to it?  If you, say, `curl -v $(minikube service --url door-control-service)`, what gets printed out?

Comment: Calls to `minikube service --url door-control-service` just hang. I assume what is happening is that it tries to connect to the socket before presenting the URL; since it's unable to do so, it never ends up displaying a URL at all. I figured that i would never want to connect to the node port in normal workflow, but the fact that it does not seem to be serving up traffic even inside the network seems bad.